# Bending arrows in tkz in certain direction

Tags: graphs, tkz-graph, tkz-berge

I have the following code which gives the attached picture.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [->, >=stealth', auto, thick,
    main node/.style=
    {circle, fill=black!30, draw, minimum size=.3cm, inner sep=0pt]},
    scale=2
    ]
    \newcommand\vx{0.5}
    \newcommand\vy{.5}
    \newcommand\fx{1} % 4.x
    \node[main node] (*) at (-\vx,  0 ) {$*$};

    \node[main node] (n) at ( \vx, \vy) {$n$};
    \node[main node] (m) at (\vx, -\vy) {$m$};

    \node (x_1) at (-2*\vx,-\vy) {$x_1 $};
    \node (x_mid) at (-2*\vx,0) {$... $};
    \node (x_i) at (-2*\vx,\vy) {$x_i$};
    \node (y_1) at (4*\vx,\vy) {$y_1$};
    \node (y_mid) at (4*\vx,0) {$...$};
    \node (y_j) at (4*\vx,-\vy) {$y_j$};
    \path[-]
    (*) 
    edge node {} (m) 
    edge node {} (n) 

    ;
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={->}]
    \draw (*) --(x_1);
    \draw (*) -- (x_mid); 
    \draw (*) -- (x_i);
    \draw (*) -- (y_1);
    \draw (*) -- (y_mid); 
    \draw (*) -- (y_j);
    \end{scope}  

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: The image of the above code]

However I would like to replace the arrows on the right with something that looks like the second picture. I need the arrows to go along a similar path and then diverge. Can anyone please give me some tips? It would be great if I could include a circle like shown as well.

[image: The result that I am looking for]

Comment: Your title has bend which to me means curved but your image has lines going straight with a kink midway.  Do you have a preference between the two cases?

Comment: By bend I meant straight lines with kinks as you say. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new node at a useful position, e.g. `2*\vx,0`, and draw the lines via that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [->, >=stealth', auto, thick,
    main node/.style=
    {circle, fill=black!30, draw, minimum size=.3cm, inner sep=0pt]},
    scale=2
    ]
    \newcommand\vx{0.5}
    \newcommand\vy{.5}
    \newcommand\fx{1} % 4.x
    \node[main node] (*) at (-\vx,  0 ) {$*$};

    \node[main node] (n) at ( \vx, \vy) {$n$};
    \node[main node] (m) at (\vx, -\vy) {$m$};

    \node (x_1) at (-2*\vx,-\vy) {$x_1 $};
    \node (x_mid) at (-2*\vx,0) {$... $};
    \node (x_i) at (-2*\vx,\vy) {$x_i$};
    \node (y_1) at (4*\vx,\vy) {$y_1$};
    \node (y_mid) at (4*\vx,0) {$...$};
    \node (y_j) at (4*\vx,-\vy) {$y_j$};
    \node [draw,circle,minimum size=6mm] (kink) at (2*\vx,0) {}; %%% <-- added
    \path[-]
    (*) 
    edge node {} (m) 
    edge node {} (n) 

    ;
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={->}]
    \draw (*) --(x_1);
    \draw (*) -- (x_mid); 
    \draw (*) -- (x_i);
    \draw (*) -- ([yshift=1mm]kink.center) -- (y_1); %% added middle coordinate
    \draw (*) -- (y_mid); 
    \draw (*) -- ([yshift=-1mm]kink.center) -- (y_j); %% added middle coordinate
    \end{scope}  

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```